# Is a separate message file library for my native Win32 service necessary?

Tags: c++, winapi, service, event-log

We've got an old legacy win32 service, developed with C++, and we've just recently noticed that when the service starts up and stops, there is an informational message in the event logs about our missing event descriptions. To be more precise, the message looks like this:

> The description for Event ID 0 from source [application] cannot be
> found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on
> your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install
> or repair the component on the local computer.

So we understand what this means, basically we're missing a library which has a message table compiled into it. This way when the event ID for changing status (start/stop) arrives, it can look up the message and print it in the event logs.

The question is, for these universal messages (changing status etc) which pretty much every service is going to have, surely there are default message table that we can use, rather than having to go to the trouble of creating another project, just for this, adding registries and updating our installer.

Seems like a lot of hassle for something that should surely be a default somewhere? Like the standard win32 error messages?

I've created a number of managed services in the past, and I'm pretty sure we didn't need to do anything like this before!

Comment: .NET hides this fact from you by providing its own message file that contains exactly 1 message of the form "%s".  Building a message file is really not that big of a deal.  If you've already got a resource file you can just include the message table in it.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I was thinking that it always had to be a separate library containing just the message table, but if I can include it in my service exe, that'll be a lot easier! Still need to add registries I guess, but it ain't too bad. Just wish the documentation around this was a bit better. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to wrap this up, I guess the answer is that the a new message table/file is always required, regardless (so no there are no default messages you can use), so I'll just have to chuck in a message table into my services resource file and add a registry entry to the installer.

Still find it baffling thought that every native service has it's own 'service has stopped/started' message...!

Thanks!

Comment: Well, there are system supplied messages for SCM actions (start, stop, etc).  The ATL service code unfortunately adds its own start and stop messages, and without a message file you will get the behavior you see.  You can modify the ATL code to remove those log messages if it really bothers you.